# Logcat error while getting data from Sqlitedatabase to listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

and my XML file is

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

in these database i am getting values from database and displaying them in a listview.
my main activity is 
      package com.example.kern;

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Second extends ListActivity {

DatabaseAdapter helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
 private CursorAdapter dataSource;
 private static final String fields[] = { "Name", "Numb"};
 ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    helper=new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    helper.open();
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    Cursor data = db.query("Mycon", fields,null, null, null, null, null);


    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.activity_second, data, fields, 
            new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.number });

     lv.setAdapter(dataSource);
}

}
```

and mydatabase adapter class is
     package com.example.kern;

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.util.Log;

 import com.example.kern.DatabaseAdapter;
 import com.example.kern.DatabaseAdapter.DatabaseHelper;

 public class DatabaseAdapter {

 DatabaseHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    static final int VERSION=2;
    static final String DATA_NAME="Mycontsc";
    private static final String query =  "create table Mycon(id Integer primary
       key,Name text,Numb text)";  //the query has been changed
    private final Context mCtx;


     public DatabaseAdapter(Context ctx) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
        }

            //DatabaseHelper has become a subclass
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATA_NAME, null, VERSION);
                        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            arg0.execSQL(query); 
        } 

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

     public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
         helper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
            db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
                db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

      public void close() {
            helper.close();
        }

    public long AddDetail(String name,String num)
    { 
        ContentValues vals=new ContentValues();
        vals.put("Name",name);
        vals.put("Numb", num);
        long a=db.insert("Mycon", null, vals);
        return a;

    } 


       }
```

it is showing null pointer exception in logcat

```
 09-18 10:32:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-18 10:32:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
 start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kern/com.example.kern.Second}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 10:32:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 10:32:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(2286):     at
com.example.kern.Second.onCreate(Second.java:29)
```

please check the program and give me the solution,it is  showing  exception,alerady there is values in the database and i am retriving them..

Comment: The error is there "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-18 09:19:53.171: E/AndroidRuntime(26528):   at
 com.example.kern.Second.onCreate(Second.java:25)" in onCreate of class Second line25. At that point is your db instancied ?

Comment: try `Second extends ListActivity`

Comment: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` If you changed the activity to `ListActivity` (which your code does not show), you need to have a `ListView` with this id in the layout file.

Comment: where should i have to place this 'android.R.id.list' please give me suggestion i am new to android

Comment: @NareshCherry check my edit 2 in my answer

Comment: @NareshCherry there are many mistakaes. Does this work  `private static final String query =  "create table Mycon(id Integer primary
       key,Name text,Numb text)"`? and try using `helper` instead of `db.

Comment: yess table is created in database,if i use helper it is showing error @Raghunandan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor data = db.query("Mycon", fields,null, null, null, null, null);
```

You haven't initialized your `db` object.

Looks like you already have the initialization code i.e. `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass and so on in `DatabaseAdapter`. Call `getReadableDatabase()` on the helper to get an `SQLiteDatabase` object you can run `query()` on.

Comment: ya done but is showing exception in logcat,please check it out i have edited logcat

Comment: how to initialize 'db' please send me @laalto